# Autolayout aligning stack fixed 3x3 buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I need some help with Auto layout. I'm trying to achieve the following:

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8O5a.png)

[But when I run the app I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0BQ0.png)

The end result should be:

- three buttons on top
- three buttons below
- fixed width and height 80x80
- centered of the screen.

[This is how I used Autolayout for the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w7zP.png)

[When I fix the width and checked off top, right, bottom, and left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtIGT.png)

[This is the results I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USZBC.png)

I hope someone can shed some light. I thought I knew how to use Autolayout but I guess I don't lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another view as the container. Position it centred horizontally and centred vertically, and pin its width and height. Now you can position your child views how you like.

Comment: I don't really understand the method you are suggesting, could you elaborate on the "using another view as container" part? I actually solved my problem when I saw the word container, I stacked the top three buttons bottom three buttons and horizontally centred them.

Comment: I just meant a container as in a parent view, so inside the main view there is one parent view, and inside the parent view there is all your buttons. Now you can position the parent however you want and all the buttons will come along for the ride.

Comment: Oh! I never used the container object. That's great solution too. Thank you.